# Rectangular connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, edge-connector

Which kind of connector is this?

[image: Unknown connector]
[image: Unknown connector]

[image: Side view]

Comment: are there any symbols on the connector? ... look for markings everywhere ... they may be very small and may be printed on the edge of the plastic

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the reply, yes, I added a pic.

Comment: very good picture ... the logo is difficult to determine ... maybe sideways lighting would enhance the detail

Comment: A genderless connector like that is uncommon. I doubt we can identify it.

Comment: What's the pin pitch?

Comment: @Hearth since I have no documentation for this connector (the schematics says that’s just a generic 6 pin connector) I measured it and should be 2.54mm from the centre of one pin to the center of the other.

Comment: Does anyone know how could I connect it to a new board that I made? This is the schematic of an old organ to which I’d like to build a midi “expansion board” but I need to figure out how to connect this connector.

Comment: This looks like one of the old AMP connector series. Check out TE Connectivety AMPMODU MTE series https://www.te.com/usa-en/plp/ampmodu-pcb-connectors-ampmodu-mte/Zn6mY30mxX27xE.html

Comment: @Lundin thank you, I’ve just checked it out… to me it doesn’t seem the same thing because comparing them, if you notice, the one in my pictures hasn’t the single pins housed separately, they are on the same plate; the socket is more similar to a card edge connector…